# Can anyone explain how this block of code works?

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
function f(num) {
    if (num<1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return f(num-1) + f(num-2);
}

f(5); // 13
```

I investigated this code in the debugger but it's still unclear to me how it works. I see it as some kind of recursion, but don't get it at all.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Google Fibonacci

Comment: This is the basic fibonacci series program. Instead of clearing how the program working you should clear the logic to generate the fibonacci series.

Answer (score 2):

There are essentially two forms of recursion direct and indirect. However, in either case any proper form of recursion must abide by three rules which makes it recursive.

> 1.) A recursive algorithm must have a base case.
>
> 2.) A recursive algorithm must change its state and move toward the base case.
>
> 3.) A recursive algorithm must call itself, recursively.

The intention for using a recursion algorithms focuses on taking a relatively mid to large problems and breaking them into smaller problems which can be solved iteratively or until the "base case" condition has been proven true.

```
function f(num) {
    if (num<=1) { // (1) Base case condition 
        return 1; // (2.b) moving forward once the base case is true
    }
     // (3) the function calling itself
    // also (2.a) changed state - (i.e., the param value is being decremented or "unwound" with each pass of recursion (i.e., method call)
    return f(num-1) + f(num-2); 
}
f(5); // Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2 (Fibonacci Number Series)
```

Resources:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/
- https://medium.com/launch-school/recursive-fibonnaci-method-explained-d82215c5498e
- https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/recursive-algorithms/a/the-factorial-function
- https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/recursive-algorithms/a/recursive-factorial
- https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/Recursion/TheThreeLawsofRecursion.html
- https://www.natashatherobot.com/recursion-factorials-fibonacci-ruby/

Comment: not a problem, glad it was helpful. if you found it useful, I would appreciate it if you marked it down as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple recursion implementation of calculating the num-th Fibonacci number(1 1 2 3 5 8....). And it has a small bug. It should be:

```
function f(num) {
    if (num<=1) { // should be <= 1 instead of <, to handle when num = 1, otherwise it'll end up with f(0)+f(-1)
        return 1;
    }
    return f(num-1) + f(num-2);
}
```

You can try to write down by hand and simulate some simple cases, which I think is really helpful when you study algorithms.

For example:

```
f(0) -> 0 is less than 1, return 1, thus f(0) = 1
f(1) -> 1 is less than or equal to 1, return 1, thus f(1) = 1
f(2) -> 2 is greater than 1, return f(1) + f(0), which we know from above, is 1 + 1, thus f(2) = 2
f(3) -> 3 is greater than 1, return f(2) + f(1), 2 + 1, thus f(3) = 3
f(4) -> 4 is greater than 1, return f(3) + f(2), 3 + 2, thus f(4) = 5
```

I bet you see the patterns now. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is recursion. It's a fibonacci series. Step through it slowly.

Start with a simple example:

f(0) = 1  (as num <1)

Increase to 1

- f(1) = f(0) + f(-1) = 2

(as num = 1, but f(num-1) and f(num-2) are both less than 1 (and so each return 1)

increase to 2:

f(2) = f(2-1) + f(0) = f(1) + f(-1) = 3

we've solved f(1) and f(-1) already so we know the total returned is 2

increase to 3:
f(3) = f(3-1) + f(3-2) = f(2) + f(1) = 3 + 2 = 5

Remembering that the algorithm is expanding out each step fully (not relying on previous solutions so to speak). so this last example would look more like:

f(3) = f(2) + f(1) = (f(1) +f(0)) + (f(0)+f(-1)) = (f(0) + f(-1)) + 1 + 1 + 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5

Comment: sorry for a kinda stupid question, but I really want to know what is the purpose of the function.
`f(5)` returns **8** and thanks to all the answers to my question, I can understand why and how it works.
However, what does 8 and 5 stand for? _What's the connection?_
8 is nor the 5th element in the Fibonacci sequence neither the sum of the previous 5 items, 5 is not the index of 8 in the array (even if there was an array). 

I hope you understand my question. I mean, there would be some purpose if, for example, I want to know the 5th number in a sequence or smth like that.

Comment: No it doesn't: markL's answer above has a *correction*, which gives different (correct for fibonacci) answers, as the base case is one step further away (due to <= vs <): F(5) = f(4) + f(3) from the worked through examples in our answers above, in my example, f(3) = 5, in marks f(3) = 3. Using the original code, f(4) = 8, and so f(5) = 5+8 = 13. In the fibonacci sequence, it should be 8, but that requires the change that markL has implemented on line 2 of the code (<=)

Comment: A fibonacci sequence is where each number is the sum of the previous two numbers. f(5) returns the 5th number in the sequence (or at least should)

Comment: TheoNeUpKID's answer above, is a good resource to research this. I recommend those resources too!

Comment: well, I also thought that we should receive the 5th number in the sequence

however, the sequence should be 0 1 1 2 3 5 8;
and 8 is not the 5th element

Comment: there's no zero value, the zero'th element is 1--> f(0) = 1

Comment: omg, sorry, there was a 0 as a starting point in every example of creating an array of Fibonacci sequence, so I came back to this code and started thinking why 5th is 8.